# How to pass argument to Node.js behind gulp

Tags: node.js, debugging, gulp

I want to pass `--inspect` to node.js that run gulp . 
there is a way to do that ?

Comment: node --inspect --debug-brk  gulpfile.js

Comment: nice but how i select the task himself

Comment: from webstorm gulp debug


`C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WebStorm 2017.1\bin\runnerw.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" --debug-brk=58486 --expose_debug_as=v8debug C:\CODE\bravo_snippet\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js --color --gulpfile C:\CODE\bravo_snippet\gulpfile.js serve-dev

Comment: try below the package [/gulp-node-inspector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-node-inspector)

Comment: i saw it, but not full understated what it should do